# How to stop web-app from refreshing every time WIFI reconnects

Tags: android, django, angular

I am relatively (1 year) new to web app development and I currently have an Angular 5 front end and Django back-end app.

Every time I am on a tablet or smartphone and the wifi reconnects (goes from one router to another) or I switch the wifi off and back on again immediately, my app reloads by itself. Does not matter if it's Chrome or Firefox.

The thing is, I have opened other websites as well in a few tabs, and when I switch my wifi off and on again, **ONLY MY APP** refreshes. This is extremely frustrating cause I loose any information that was being entered in a form. (And some forms may be long)

The fact that it is only my app reloading when the wifi comes back on, makes me think that I have some settings somewhere that other sites do not have. But I do not even know where to begin to look.

I have look everywhere on the internet for anything for 2 days now but have not found an answer.

Comment: a web app not refresh every time wifi reconnects. So **you** are who was saying to your application refresh. Check the routine where you get the connection

Comment: is this only when you're developing locally? `ng serve` opens a websocket. interrupting the socket causes reload.

Comment: @joh04667 You are indeed correct, this is when I am developing locally with ng serve. So if this is the expected behavior then you will be right. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Not developing locally. `ng serve` opens up a websocket listening to port 4200. Reconnecting to that port (which sends another GET) will reconnect the websocket. It's just the nature of a socket connection. Developing locally and connecting via localhost should not cause any interruptions.